# How do I force Noise to rescan my music library?

Tags: music, import

I have copied a few new albums (MP3, properly id3-tagged) into my local music folder, unfortunately they don't show up in Noise.
Restarting Noise didn't help either, even restarting elementary OS had no effect.

How do I enforce a rescan of my music library in Noise?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run this command in terminal:

```
rm ~/.local/share/noise/*.db
```

Then [re-scan your music library](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/304/3).

Comment: are the files `*.db` the cache of where the music is? And what do you mean by "Then re-scan your music library."?

Comment: @Tim * .db files are the base of music Noise. After removing Noise again ask to rescan your music library. Your way of doing almost the same thing.

Comment: could you edit to explain that because the way the answer reads is "do this" and then "do what you want to do and are asking about" ;-) I can link my answer if you want?

Comment: @Tim I'm not against :)

Answer (score 5):

Open Music, and click Settings:

[image]

Then change the location to Desktop, then back to Music.