# Is there a way to make Noise automatically update music library?

Tags: music

I am always adding new music. Is there a way Noise can update my library without having to import?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, this should be regulated by one of the options in the settings dialogue, as I understand it.

It has not been working for me, however and I have to [re-scan the library manually](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/302/how-do-i-force-noise-to-rescan-my-music-library?rq=1) every time I want Music to acknowledge a change I made.