# Music (Noise) doesn't save track information

Tags: release-juno, music, audio, audio-player

I just installed Juno. I copied over my music files and apparently some of them were missing track information because they weren't getting grouped together (by album and artist).

So I right-clicked on the music files, selected "Edit Song Info..." and added the missing track information. Clicked "Save", but it didn't save because if I went back to the track information, it was still missing.

Installed Rhythmbox and I was able to save the missing track information.  As soon as I changed the information there, Rhythmbox would automatically re-organize it and group it properly.

Went back into Music (Noise), but it didn't pick up the new information. Some of the music file were still saying "unknown artist" or "unknown album". Tried removing and the re-adding them to the library, but that didn't change anything.

So...
1) Why isn't Music saving track information?
2) Why doesn't Music pick up the changes automatically and reload the Music files when the changes were made by another program?

Aside from these issues, I like Noise. It comes close to the look and feel of Banshee which would be my favorite player if it was still supported.

UPDATE: I had an old laptop with Freya installed on it. I can edit music files with Music there. I have a VM with Loki and I could edit music files there too. Just can't edit them on Juno

UPDATE#2: I found the answer to my second question about how to get Music to pick up changes. I found that here: [How do I force Noise to rescan my music library?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/302/how-do-i-force-noise-to-rescan-my-music-library?rq=1)
But I still don't know why Music doesn't save any changes made to track information.

UPDATE #3: Someone just opened up an issue on this:
https://github.com/elementary/music/issues/451

This might also be a related issue:
https://github.com/elementary/music/issues/156